# MinerGate mining Monero cryptocurrency with ArubaCloud

Tags: mining, cpu-mining

For 21 days I've been mining Monero cryptocurrency using the VPS from ArubaCloud. At the beginning, mining was about 25h / s. For 3 days I have been having problems with mining, the speed has decreased to 5h / s and in addition I lose connection with my miner.

Do you know what can be the reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When mining on a VPS drops, the likely reason is that you either got throttled by the admin, or your VM shares hardware with other VMs which are competing for the CPU time.

If this VPS provider can migrate VMs on other hardware, it might also be the case that the previous hardware had (and exposed to guests) AES-NI instructions, and the new one does not. AES-NI on Intel/AMD are instructions which speed up Cryptonight mining a lot.

Comment: What should I do now?

Comment: @Paul Don't mine on a VPS.